# Install @AngularFire Error:The package that you are trying to add does not support schematics

Tags: web-development, google-cloud-platform, npm

I am trying to install @angular/fire using the `ng add @angular/fire` command. However, I keep getting the error:

```
The package that you are trying to add does not support schematics. You can try using a different version of the package or contact the package author to add ng-add support.
```

It then says that version 0.0.0 of @angular/fire is installed which is clearly an error.

I am using 12.0.0 of angular.

Comment: Try using npm : `npm install -g @angular/fire`.